# Spring Jpa: change FetchType for entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have `Foo` entity with one field annotated with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`. Usually this field is not needed, but in some queries we need all elements with all related entities. I don't want to query database one by one to get associated entities (n+1 select issue). Is there any way to specify fetchType? Something like:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository <Foo, String> {
  List<Foo> findAll(FetchType fetchType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<Address> address;
```

Let's say you have above code. 
You can avoid n+1 issue if you do `address.size()`

```
getAdress().size()
```

so that hibernate will load all elements at once instead of loading one by one.

Comment: But `@ManyToOne` don't have type `List`, you confused it with `@OneToMany`